# UDP Flooding locally?

Tags: ip, lag, udp, local

Could somebody tell me what the IP 27.27.27.27 is and why this works with UDP flooding?

Flooding 27.27.27.27 lags my entire network, but flooding my local IP 192.168.1.10 or 127.0.0.1 does nothing.

Are there any ways to isolate the the lag effects when flooding 27.27.27.27 to my local machine only?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you have misinterpreted the question. I am not asking for the whois data on the IP, but rather why when I UDP Flood this IP it lags my entire network?

Comment: You are asking why does UDP flooding (very naughty) an IP address on WAN in China cause your machine to be sluggish compared to flooding your LAN?  hmm  I think your ISP is on to you.

Comment: I am not using it to cheat, I am using it to experiment with interpolation and other lag compensation methods to improve hit-registration in some games. I want to know why instigating a UDP Flood on 27.27.27.27 causes my entire network to lag, but not when I flood any local IP? So I was wondering if 27.27.27.27 is some sort of special IP related to UDP sockets?

Comment: Then how can I cause only my system to lag and not my entire network with UDP floods? As flooding local IPs such as 127.0.0.1 does nothing.